# JavaScript boolen variable with if executes even when value is false

Tags: javascript, boolean, conditional-statements

I am calling a JS function from vb.net code behind, using RegisterClientScriptBlock

Initially this variable is a string having value as (true/false), then I parse it using custom code to booelan and I am passing this Boolean value as one of the parameter to a JavaScript function.
Inside this JS function I am checking if that bool value is true or not using the below code.
Now even though the **bool value is false, the if(boolVariable) line of code is executing**.

If I do an explicit check if(boolVariable == true) then it behaves as expected.

My understanding is that if(boolvariable) block should execute only if the  boolVariable value is true.
I am missing something ? Please guide.

Vb.net code

```
Dim jsCall As String = String.Format("jsfunction('{0}','{1}');", variable1, CustomParsers.Boolean(boolVariable)) // custom parser value will be true or false

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock([GetType](), "script", jsCall, True)
```

JS code

```
function jsfunction(variable1,boolVariable) {
       
     if (boolVariable) {  // though boolVariable value is false this block is executing
          // do something
        }
        
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that `boolVariable` is a boolean (and not a string)? What is outputted if you were to add `console.log(typeof boolVariable);`? `"false" != true`, but `"false"` is truthy, which is why I'm asking this.

Comment: `jsfunction('{0}','{1}');` seems suspiciously like you're passing strings.

Comment: @theusaf - Yes you were right, console shows - type of:string , though I pass boolean
Then how do I check it ?

Comment: @Nietthedarkabsol - jsfunction('{0}','{1}');
When I give without quotes like jsfunction('{0}',{1}) - It throes an error saying False is undefined.

Comment: In JavaScript, `False/True` are lowercase: `true`/`false`